# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

In my NextJS application, I am trying to fetch json data from my mongodb database in `getInitialProps` like so:

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const res = await 
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/endpoint');
    const json = await res.json();
    return { data: json };
}
```

I then try to render the component:

```
  render() {
       return (
            <div>
              <h1>{this.props.data}</h1>.  
            </div>)
  }
```

However, I am getting the following error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, property_key}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Here's the data:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

import React from 'react'

class Home extends React.Component {

  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {

    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/endpoint');
    const json = await res.json();
    return { data: json };
  }

  render() {
    return (<div><h1>{this.props.data}</h1></div>)
  }
  
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Have you checked `this.props.data`? What's being passed in that?

Comment: I've updated it with the full code.

Comment: I meant to ask what's the value of the `this.props.data`. Add a `console.log(this.props.data)` statement in the render function and see what's being logged there.

Comment: my mongodb collection is being logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong: You first have to JSON.stringify the data. Then, when you are using the data, do JSON.parse.